# UITextField returns value held before edit

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have textField. For that textField, I added the following target and function.

```
textField.addTarget(target: self, action: #selector(self.textDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

func textDidChanged() {
      label.text = textField.text
}
```

Strange thing I encounter is whenever the textDidChanged is called textField returns the previous state of value.

Eg: **What I entered in TextFiled**   -->   **What I got in Label**

```
       "a"    ---->             ""
       "aa"   ---->             "a"
       "a"    ---->             "aa"
```

textField.text return value before my edit.

Is it something wrong in my doing. Guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing anything with `shouldChangeCharactersIn`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Can you provide the exact code with more context? For example, action accepts a selector, you aren't using one, typo's, etc

Comment: textField ? textfield. Are they same?

Comment: @rmaddy why is that relevant? If he does something in `shouldChangeCharacters`, the actual textField would also not contain the character contradicting the example in his question.

Comment: Why don't you use the relevant methods from `UITextFieldDelegate`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor There is no relevant method in `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i think you are confusing it with the one we do have in `UITextViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChanged), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
}

@objc func textDidChanged() {
    label.text = textfield.text
}
```

This works in Xcode10.